# Python etree: Create nested XML from CSV, grouped on two values

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm very new to Python. I have the following problem:

I have a ~5000 row CSV with employment data. The first column is the employee uniqe ID (Personnummer), the second column is an employment number (Anstallningsnummer). Every employee may have several employmens, resulting in a list like this:

> Personnummer,Anstallningsnummer,From,Tom,Avtalstillhorighet,Pensionsalder,Anstallningstyp,Avslutsorsak
> **198709291234**,**1**,2011-03-01,2011-03-31,PA03,65,H3,S7
> **198709291234**,**2**,2013-03-01,2013-03-31,PA03,65,H3,S7

I try to create a nested XML that groups the records first on the first column (personnummer) written in the format "Arbetstagare Personnummer="*cell value*".

Then group on the second column (Anställningsnummer) written in the format Anstallning Anstallningsnummer="*cell value*"

And then write out the remaining six columns grouped under the tag < Period >, restart with the next Anstallningsnummer (if existing), end the Personnummer tag and go to the next row. The end result should look like this:

```
        <Arbetstagare Personnummer="198709291234">
            <Anstallning Anstallningsnummer="1">
                <Period>
                    <From>2011-03-01</From>
                    <Tom>2011-03-31</Tom>
                    <Avtalstillhorighet>PA1601</Avtalstillhorighet>
                    <Pensionsalder>65</Pensionsalder>
                    <Anstallningstyp>H3</Anstallningstyp>
                    <Avslutsorsak>S7</Avslutsorsak>
                </Period>
            </Anstallning>
            <Anstallning Anstallningsnummer="2">
                <Period>
                    <From>2013-03-01</From>
                    <Tom>2013-03-31</Tom>
                    <Avtalstillhorighet>PA1601</Avtalstillhorighet>
                    <Pensionsalder>65</Pensionsalder>
                    <Anstallningstyp>H3</Anstallningstyp>
                    <Avslutsorsak>S7</Avslutsorsak>
                </Period>
            </Anstallning>
        </Arbetstagare>
```

At the moment my Python code looks like this:

```
from lxml import etree
from itertools import groupby
import csv

with open(Leverans_python.csv') as data_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data_file)
    f = lambda x: x['Personnummer']
    data = sorted(list(reader), key=f)
    root = etree.Element('Arbetstagarlista')
    for k, g in groupby(data, key=f):
        Personnummer = etree.SubElement(root, 'Personnummer')
        Anstallningsnummer = etree.SubElement(Personnummer, 'Anstallningsnummer')
        Period = etree.SubElement(Anstallningsnummer, 'Period')
        for entry in g:
            From = etree.SubElement(Period, 'From')
            Tom = etree.SubElement(Period, 'Tom')
            Avtalstillhorighet = etree.SubElement(Period, 'Avtalstillhorighet')
            Pensionsalder = etree.SubElement(Period, 'Pensionsalder')
            Anstallningstyp = etree.SubElement(Period, 'Anstallningstyp')
            Avslutsorsak = etree.SubElement(Period, 'Avslutsorsak')
            From.text = entry['From']
            Tom.text = entry['Tom']
            Avtalstillhorighet.text = entry['Avtalstillhorighet']
            Pensionsalder.text = entry['Pensionsalder']
            Anstallningstyp.text = entry['Anstallningstyp']
            Avslutsorsak.text = entry['Avslutsorsak']
            Avtalstillhorighet.text = entry['Avtalstillhorighet']
            Pensionsalder.text = entry['Pensionsalder']

    with open('my_data.xml', 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

And the result I get looks like

```
  <Personnummer>
    <Anstallningsnummer>
      <Period>
        <From>2011-03-01</From>
        <Tom>2011-03-31</Tom>
        <Avtalstillhorighet>PA03</Avtalstillhorighet>
        <Pensionsalder>65</Pensionsalder>
        <Anstallningstyp>H3</Anstallningstyp>
        <Avslutsorsak>S7  </Avslutsorsak>
        <From>2013-03-01</From>
        <Tom>2013-03-31</Tom>
        <Avtalstillhorighet>PA03</Avtalstillhorighet>
        <Pensionsalder>65</Pensionsalder>
        <Anstallningstyp>H3</Anstallningstyp>
        <Avslutsorsak>S7</Avslutsorsak>
      </Period>
    </Anstallningsnummer>
  </Personnummer>
```

So to break down the problems:

1. My code now only groups on column one, putting the values of column 3-6 from both employment 1 and 2 in the same < period > tag. How do I create a new group based on the value in col 2 under the first group so that there will be two sets of < Anstallningsnummer > tags (including the value from col 3-6) if an employee has two employments?
2. How do I go about to write out the first row as < Arbetstagare Personnummer="*cell value eg 198709291234*" > ?

Comment: Does each unique employee id have two employment numbers or can each id have only one or more than two?

Comment: No, they have at least one, but could have several